# How to apply custom styling on TextField in Office UI Fabric React so that the TextField component fits the dimensions of the table cell

Tags: react-typescript, spfx, react-css-modules, office-ui-fabric-react

I'm working on SPFX webpart on prem using React 15.6.2, Office UI Fabric React v5.135.6. I don't have access to the ITextFieldStyles library. I want to make the height of the TextField component to fit in accordance to the td dimensions. The approach method that I would prefer is to set the height and width component of the TextField root component to 100%.

Here's the React tsx code

```
<td className= { styles.sukukRemarksCol }>
  <TextField
    className= { styles.textField }
    multiline= { true }
    resizable= { false }
    borderless= { true }
    autoAdjustHeight= { false }
    value= { this.state.listingRequirementsRemarks }
    onBlur= {() => this.getListingRequirementsRemarks}
    style={
      {
        padding: "1%",
      }
    }
  >
  </TextField>
</td>
```

SCSS code

```
:global {
  .ms-TextField.root_cd8a9909.ms-TextField--multiline.rootIsMultiline_cd8a9909.ms-TextField--borderless.rootIsBorderless_cd8a9909 {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
.sukukRemarksCol {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.textField {
  min-height: max-content;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2%;
}
```

I tried with the current approach shown above but apparently it doesn't seem to work, may I know what went wrong?